# What is a localized borel space?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

This question is based on the presentation in [Kallenberg's Foundations of Modern Probability 3e.](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-61871-1)

Call the measurable spaces $(S,\mathcal S)$ and $(T,\mathcal T)$ Borel isomorphic if there is a bijection $f:T\to S$ with $f$ and $f^{-1}$ measurable. Call $(S,\mathcal S)$ a Borel space if it is Borel isomorphic to a borel subset of $[0,1]$. (In particular, any polish space is Borel.)

Next, given a Borel space $(S,\mathcal S)$, we choose a "localizing sequence" $E_n \uparrow S$ with $E_n\in \mathcal S$. Let $B\subset S$. If $B\subset E_n$ for some $n$, then we say $B$ is bounded and we by denote $\hat{\mathcal S}$ the ring of bounded (measurable) sets. In particular, if $\mathcal S$ is generated by a metric $\rho$, then we may take $\hat{\mathcal S}$ to be all $\rho$ bounded sets.

The notion of signed measure is then introduced. Let $(S,\mathcal S)$ be a localized Borel space and let $\nu: \hat{\mathcal S}\to \mathbb R$. Say that $\nu$ is a signed measure if $\nu \cup_n B_n = \sum \nu B_n$ for any $B_i$ disjoint with the series converging absolutely. What is going on here?

On the other hand, in the [second edition](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-4015-8) of the book, there is no discussion of the notion of a "localized Borel space."  Indeed, a signed measure is presented in the usual way. Namely, let $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ be a measurable space. $\nu:\mathcal A\to\mathbb R$ is a bounded signed measure if $\nu \cup B_n = \sum \nu B_n$ for any disjoint $B_i$ with the series converging absolutely.

Why do we need to introduce localized Borel spaces?

As another example, in the second edition, one has the usual definition of locally finite measure. Namely, $\mathcal X$ is a topological space and $\mathcal B$ its Borel $\sigma$-field. Call $\mu$ locally finite if every point $x\in \mathcal X$ has a neighborhood with finite measure.

In the third edition, it is instead defined as let $(S,\mathcal S)$ be a localized Borel space and $\mu$ a measure. Say $\mu$ is locally finite if $\mu<\infty$ on $\hat{\mathcal S}$.

Comment: $B$ and $E_n$ are not defined in the third paragraph. I suspect, definitions are related to moderated measures (those measures which have support in countable union of sets with finite measure). Moderated measures are needed for Fubini theorem in the case space is not $\sigma$-compact. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_measure

Comment: fixed typo, thanks @dsh

Comment: Addition to previous comment. Note that the second edition (paragraph 5) refers to bounded measures and moderated measures are generalizations of bounded measures. I think $\nu|E_n$ is assumed to be bounded measure in paragraph 4, so you need to check proofs where localization is used. Countable additivity is not sufficient in some cases and one needs regular measures (like Radon measures).